# How to abort silently?

Tags: evaluation

I want to Abort[] an evaluation without generating this message:

```
$Aborted
```

Is there a way to do this? This messages modifies my notebook, and I don't want this to happen.

Comment: This is not a message, it's the result of the computation.  It's what the kernel returns when the computation is aborted.  I don't think there's a way to turn this off.  If you explain *why* you need to avoid this, we might be able to come up with alternative solutions.  Generally, you can wrap the input with `CheckAbort[..., Null]`.

Comment: I am trying to make a persistence code for my notebooks. If I catch the $Aborted, it doesn't abort. I think there is no solution.

Comment: Well, you can use something like this: `$Post = Function[code,Unevaluated[code]/.$Aborted->Null, HoldAll]`.

Comment: If you are aborting for time see `TimeConstrained`, where a `;` *does* suppress the `$Aborted` message/result.

Comment: There was another problem, my abort was not aborting (I had to use Interrupt[]), so I think the second comment already solves the problem. Leonid's is the same basically.

Comment: My notebooks take a long time to calculate, so I made a code that saves the notebook contents to a file using Save[], and on the next evaluation of the notebook it verifies if the notebook last modification date is older than the saved file. Based on this it chooses to calculate all the notebook again, or just load the saved file.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Have I overlooked something in not including the attribute `HoldAll`? I figured the expression comes out of the kernel in an evaluated state anyway. I was unable to figure out a case where the `HoldAll` argument matters. By the way the expression `{Clear@c, c, c = 0}`, gets handled differently in the presence/absence of `$Post`, but that's just a joke :).

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom You are probably right. I guess I just used the mental pattern I had for `$Pre`, automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This is a comment turned into an answer as per request. Also note that I changed `==` into `===`, which seems to be crucial.*

In case you think an abort may happen at an unpredicted moment, you can set

```
$Post = Function[If[# === $Aborted, Null, #]];
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot to tell you this, I made that modification too.